# Drawing a gear with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I need some help to modify the `\gear` macro of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58828/19156) in order to be able to fill the drawn gear with a solid color.

I've tried to move the `\draw` command outside the loop, but it does not work as expected (missing semicolon???):

```
\newcommand{\gear}[3]{%
    \def\modu{#1}
    \def\Zb{#2}
    \def\AngleA{#3}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Rpr}{\Zb*\modu/2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Rb}{\Rpr*cos(\AngleA)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Rt}{\Rpr+\modu}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Rp}{\Rpr-1.25*\modu}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\AngleT}{pi/180*acos(\Rb/\Rt)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\AnglePr}{pi/180*acos(\Rb/\Rpr)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\demiAngle}{180/\Zb}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Angledecal}{(\demiAngle-2*\AnglePr)/2}

    \draw[fill=black!20] \foreach \zz in{1,2,...,\Zb}{
         ({(\zz))/\Zb*360-\Angledecal}:\Rb)
            -- (\zz/\Zb*360-\Angledecal:\Rp)
            to[bend right=\demiAngle] (\zz/\Zb*360+\Angledecal:\Rp)
            -- plot[domain=-0:\AngleT,smooth,variable=\t]
                ({{180/pi*(-\t+tan(180/pi*\t))+\zz/\Zb*360+\Angledecal}:\Rb/cos(180/pi*\t)})
            % 
            to[bend right=\demiAngle] 
                ({{180/pi*(\AngleT+tan(180/pi*-\AngleT)) +(\zz+1)/\Zb*360-\Angledecal}:
                    \Rb/cos(180/pi*-\AngleT)})
        % 
            plot[domain=-\AngleT:-0,smooth,variable=\t]
                ({{180/pi*(-\t+tan(180/pi*\t)) +(\zz+1)/\Zb*360-\Angledecal}:
                    \Rb/cos(180/pi*\t)})
    } -- cycle;
}
```

**Edit:** add missing fill color

Comment: As I see it, the `\draw` is already outside of the loop? Does replacing `\draw` with `\fill` or `\filldraw` not work?

Comment: The above example gives a missing semicolon error; in the original code, the draw is inside the loop

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. But still, why don’t you replace the `\draw` with `\fill(draw)` or just add `fill=<color>` to its optional argument? Okay, scratch that, I’ve just tested it, of course it doesn’t work with sepearate `\draw` commands.

Comment: Hem... you're right, but I was trying first to complete the drawing, and, when done, it's just a simple correction. I'll edit my most

Comment: You will need to save the result of the `\foreach` loop and use it later, i.e. `\draw\savedPath;` …

Comment: May you provide an example?

Comment: I don’t have time now, but you could take a look at these answers of mine: [(1)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82303/16595), [(2)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82505/16595). The TikZ `\foreach` loop encloses its content in a group, so you will need the global variants `\gappto` and `\xappto`.

Comment: Examples of filled and shaded cogwheels: [Drawing a cogwheel in pgf/tikz](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=21696).

Comment: I tried to do the same filling action. Solution: you can use this excellent [patch given by Andrew Stacey](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58909/14500).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thank you; I have not the time to test it yet, but it should do the job. May you fill an answer?

Comment: I've marked as a dupe, based on the premise that the problem here is a bug.