# When and how to use foreach in a path command? TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-path

Why does my code fail? Without the `foreach` my code works correctly.

Generally, when and how can I use `foreach` within a `path` command? Is this a bad practice? If so what should be the alternative?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{ myVrtxStyle/.style = {
        circle, minimum size= 4mm, fill = blue
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[myVrtxStyle = black] (u) {};
        
        \newcommand{\midSepAngle}{20};
        \newcommand{\remNi}{6}
        
        \draw (u.{135 + \midSepAngle}) to [out = {135 + \midSepAngle}, in = {135 - \midSepAngle}, looseness = 100]
        \foreach \i in {1,..., \remNi}{
            node[ myVrtxStyle, pos = {\i / \remNi} ] (C1\i) {} 
        }
        (u.{135 - \midSepAngle});
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have seen few related posts such as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58829/how-to-use-plot-in-a-foreach-loop-into-a-single-path) but I still do not understand fully what is going on.

Comment: I don't recall you can use foreach "on line". The place you can use foreach is when Ti*k*Z is not "pending". For example, between `(A)--` and `(B)`, Ti*k*Z is desperately looking for the target of the segment. You can barely place a node there; but certainly a for loop is too much. What you what is probably achievable with the library `decorations.markings`.

Comment: Foreach in the middle of a draw command is just `foreach`, no backslash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. In a path, you should use `foreach`. For historical reasons, you can also write `\foreach` instead of `foreach` (cf. section [*"14.14
   The Foreach Operation"*, p.167](https://texdoc.org/serve/pgf/0#subsection.14.14), pgfmanual v3.1.9a).
2. There are two ways of specifying a node on a line or a curve: Either explicitly by using the pos option or implicitly by placing the node “inside” a path operation (cf. sections [*"17.8
   Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly"*, p.245](https://texdoc.org/serve/pgf/0#subsection.17.8) and [*"17.9
   Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Implicitly"*, p.249](https://texdoc.org/serve/pgf/0#subsection.17.9), pgfmanual v3.1.9a).

   - Implicit example: `\draw (0,0) -- node[pos=.7]{a} (1,1);` Only the line-to (`--`) and curve-to (`..`) operations support the *implicit* way. **The `foreach` keyword is not supported by the *implicit* way.**
   - Explicit example: `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) node[pos=.7] {a};` Only the line-to (`--`), horizontal and vertical line-to (`-|` and `|-`), curve-to (`..`) and arc (`arc`) operation support the *explicit* way.
   - ***For all other path construction operations*** (like `to` on your case), ***the position placement does not work, currently*** (cf. [p.246](https://texdoc.org/serve/pgf/0#page=246), pgfmanual, v3.1.9a).

So, you must use the *explicit* way and replace your `to` operation by a curve-to (`..`) operation as in the [Andrew Stacey's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610123/14500).

Comment: I couldn't get that to work with the to path.  All my nodes ended up at the end of the path.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I forgot to test my code! I corrected my answer to finally refer to your answer.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote more for all the references!

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why it doesn't work with a `to` command - I'll have to investigate that - but with an explicit bézier curve then it does.

1. The target coordinate has to go before the foreach
2. The foreach is a key word, not a command
3. I modified your node style to take an argument as the fill colour with default blue

```
\documentclass {standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
myVrtxStyle/.style = { circle, minimum size= 4mm, fill = #1 },
myVrtxStyle/.default = blue
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[myVrtxStyle = black] 
(u) {}; 
\newcommand{\midSepAngle}{20}; 
\newcommand{\remNi}{6} 
\draw (u.{135 + \midSepAngle}) 
.. controls +(135+\midSepAngle:20) and +(135-\midSepAngle: 20) ..
(u.{135-\midSepAngle})
foreach \i in {1,..., \remNi}{ 
node[ myVrtxStyle, pos = \i/\remNi ] (C1\i) {}
}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following syntax actually works
and is almost identical to your original code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    myVrtxStyle/.style={
        circle,minimum size=4mm,fill=blue,fill=#1
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[myVrtxStyle=black](u){};
        \newcommand{\midSepAngle}{20};
        \newcommand{\remNi}{6}
        \draw
            (u.{135 +\midSepAngle})
            to
            [out={135+\midSepAngle},in={135-\midSepAngle},looseness=100]
            node foreach\i in{1,...,\remNi}[pos=\i/\remNi,myVrtxStyle](C1\i){}
            (u.{135-\midSepAngle})
        ;
        \draw foreach\i in{1,...,\remNi}{
            (C1\i)--+(-90-\i*40:1)node{\i}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remark

My comment under the question is incorrect in the manner that
you actually can use a for-loop between `(A) --` and `(B)`.
However, this for-loop cannot be an arbitrary for-loop;
it has to be a for-loop dedicated to nodes.
So
`(A) -- foreach\i in{1,2,3}{node{\i}} (B)` is bad, but
`(A) -- node foreach\i in{1,2,3}{\i} (B)` is good.

This is because when Ti*k*Z's parser
has read `(A) --` and is waiting for `(B)`,
it also keeps an eye on whether there is a `node...{...}`.
Once it sees `n`, it will collect the node specification
and store it in `\tikz@collected@onpath`, which is latter
transferred to `\tikz@tonodes` and to `\tikztonodes`.
After Ti*k*Z computed the Bézier representation of your `to path`,
it places the node specification at the end of the path like this
([tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex#L134-L140](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex#L134-L140))

```
\def\tikz@to@curve@path{%
  [every curve to]%                ⬇️ This is the main computation ⬇️
  \pgfextra{\iftikz@to@relative\tikz@to@compute@relative\else\tikz@to@compute\fi}
  \tikz@computed@path% ⬅️ this is the Bézier curve (A)..controls(B)and(C)..(D)
  \pgfextra{\tikz@updatenexttrue\tikz@updatecurrenttrue}%
  \tikztonodes% ⬅️ your nodes here (notice the plural)
}
```

So all you need to do is to make sure `\tikztonodes`
actually catches your node specifications.
In case the natural syntax fails, you can always *force it*.
For example
`to[bend left,/utils/exec=\def\tikztonodes{...}]`.

Comment: I hadn't come across the `node foreach` syntax before - thanks for posting this!  For reference, it is explained in Section 17.2.1 (of the 3.1.9a version) of the TikZ/PGF manual.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, a separate question: Could someone please tell me why my `pos` does not create equally distant nodes?

Comment: `pos` in this case is parametrized by the "time" of the Bézier curve. If you need equal distance, use `decorations.markings` because it is parametrized by arc length.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thanks.