# How to draw clipart icons in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Is there a way to draw clipart icons in tikz?
Or is there a way to export them or should I use some other software for this purpose?

I want to draw the following 5 icons:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use `\includegrapics{}` inside a tikz node, and this way "import" your icons and use them as part of a tikz picture. Of course you can give `width` option to `includegraphics` to size them appropiately. I think this is the quickest way. You can also try to recreate those icons in pure tikz, but with all those gradients, shades, etc. that will be very difficult.

Comment: It would probably be better to use e.g. Inkscape or Gimp to create those. Anyways, for the second: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58702/creating-gears-in-tikz

Comment: Depending on their size, it might be actually better to recreate them in tikz *without* gradients, shades etc. - if they are too small, they might be difficult to see anyway.

Comment: If you really need to have TikZ/PGF code for those cliparts, and they're available to you in a vector format, you could import them in Inkscape and use [this plugin](https://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/) to export them as as `tikzpicture`. However, I'm not sure how well the resulting code is suited for editing...