# Giving a gear in Tikz absolute position

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I've the following MWE of a gear :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,decorations.markings}

% #1 number of teeths
% #2 radius intern
% #3 radius extern
% #4 angle from start to end of the first arc
% #5 angle to decale the second arc from the first
% #6 internal key of the gear node
% #7 text to put inside the gear
\newcommand{\gear}[7]{
  node (#6) {#7}
  (0:#2)
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \n using {\i-1)*360/#1}] in {1,...,#1}{
    arc (\n:\n+#4:#2) {[rounded corners=1.5pt] -- (\n+#4+#5:#3)
    arc (\n+#4+#5:\n+360/#1-#5:#3)} --  (\n+360/#1:#2)
  }
}

\begin{document}

% Define the layers to draw the diagram
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

% Define block styles used later
\tikzstyle{engine} = [fill=red!20, text centered,drop shadow]

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[engine] \gear{8}{2}{2.4}{10}{2}{a}{Gear A};
%\draw[engine] (a.east)+(8,0) \gear{8}{2}{2.4}{10}{2}{b}{Gear B};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \path (a.north west)+(-4,4) node (x) {};
  \path (a.south east)+(10,-4) node (y) {};
  \path[fill=yellow!10, rounded corners, draw=black!70, dashed] (x) rectangle (y);                       
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces the following output as expected.

[image: output]

Now, I want one more gear, say Gear B, to the right of Gear A. For which I've tried uncommenting the following line in the above example:

```
\draw[engine] (a.east)+(8,0) \gear{8}{2}{2.4}{10}{2}{b}{Gear B};
```

But unfortunately It's producing something like this:

[image: wrong output]

I've tried with several other ways to get it done, but nothing worked. The gear items are superimposed over each other. Is there any way to position them absolutely ?

[Here](https://www.overleaf.com/4911378pxgyzg) is an online version of the above example which you can edit and play with.

Comment: The problem is that the `\gear` command uses absolute coordinates. Try `\draw[engine, blue] ...` to see it.

Comment: look at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58791/5355

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
\draw[engine] (a.east)+(8,0) \gear{8}{2}{2.4}{10}{2}{b}{Gear B};
```

see if this modification of above code is acceptable to you:

```
\draw[engine,xshift=60mm] \gear{8}{2}{2.4}{10}{2}{b}{Gear B};
```

**Edit:**
Alternative for above is use of `scope` (as suggested Peter Grill):

```
\begin{scope}[shift={($(a.east)+(5,0)$)}]
\draw[engine]  \gear{8}{2}{2.4}{10}{2}{b}{Gear B};
\end{scope}
```

In this case you need to add library `calc` for calculation of `shift` macro

[image]

I think that instead of `\newcommand` for drawing gear the small picture `pic` would be better choice.

Comment: Can you add the `scope` option so I can delete my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (if you do not have `pic`s because you are still with tikzpgf 2.10) you can change the definition of `\gear` to use relative coordinates (still need `calc` added to tikz packages):

```
\newcommand{\gear}[7]{
  node (#6) {#7} 
  ($(#6)+(0:#2)$)
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \n using {\i-1)*360/#1}] in {1,...,#1}{
    arc (\n:\n+#4:#2) {[rounded corners=1.5pt] -- ($(#6)+ (\n+#4+#5:#3)$)
    arc (\n+#4+#5:\n+360/#1-#5:#3)} --  ($(#6)+(\n+360/#1:#2)$)
  }
}
```

(the code in overleaf looks funny because it assumes that `($...$)` is math mode...)

[image: Result in overleaf with just changing \gear]