# A rather elaborate frame for text

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox, framed

I am creating a worksheet in TeX and would like to separate the questions using boxes. The attached file shows the box I have created to house the questions. I was wondering if anyone could write a code to describe a text box like this, as my skills aren't so advanced. The 'Q' should be centered as shown in the diagram and should only be slightly larger than the example text (which I've set at 12pt). [image]

The color of the shapes and text-box should be as they are in the diagram (dark grey). Since the problem is quite elaborate, I really would appreciate some help as I am struggling to code this myself.

Comment: Two questions:does the external box have width equal to \textwidth? Will the  text in the box  have to break across pages, or is just a title box?

Comment: Yes \textwidth would look better on the page. It's really just a box for a short question so it wouldn't break across a page.

Comment: Please always provide a minimal example showing what you've got or at least giving people something to work with. We don't know whether your document is LaTeX, plain, ConTeXt or what. And it really isn't fair to ask this and then, after getting an answer, demand that the gear be movable with the text still wrapping around it! If that is really now required for an answer, you should make it very clear in the question so that people know not to try to offer help in LaTeX. (The requirement makes this extremely difficult, perhaps impossible, in LaTeX.)

Answer (score 3):

The `bclogo` package might be a good starting point:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo} 

\begin{document}

\begin{bclogo}[logo=\bcoutil,marge=8]{Mon titre}%
\lipsum[2]
\end{bclogo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really give the right look.

Comment: The gear icon that I'm after should ideally be as sharp as possible rather than an image file that blurs on zoom. Is there any way of constructing the icon in TeX?

Comment: You can use whatever image you want with the package. If you choose a vector image, it will not blur.

Comment: see  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58702/creating-gears-in-tikz

Comment: How could I then edit it so that the box is rounded, the position of the vector can change and the text indents around the icon, as in my image?

Comment: @wrb98 Have a look at the [bclogo manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/bclogo/doc/bclogo-doc.pdf). It is in French, but it contains many illustrative examples that you will understand without French.

Comment: @wrb98 Why do you think this will blur on zoom? It is using MPS images for the default logos as far as I can tell.