# How to draw a curve from a previously calculated list of points

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I need to draw a curve from a list of points whose coordinates have been calculated beforehand in a foreach loop

I manage to generate my points and to use them independently, I think to manage to create a list, in any case, I manage to display it by cons I can not use this list in the command of drawing

```
\draw plot coordinates {....};
```

if I copy the displayed list, and replace in the plot, I get the plot.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\def\RR{5}
%calcul des coordonnées des points
%calculation of the coordinates of the points
\foreach \ii in {0, 1,2,3,...,20}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\aa}{360 * \ii/20}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rr}{\RR + \ii}
    \coordinate(P-\ii) at (\aa:\rr);
}

%dessin de la spirale/drawing of the spiral
\foreach \ii in {1,2,3,...,20}{
\node[fill=black,inner sep=0,minimum size=0.2cm,circle]at (P-\ii){};
}

%Création de la liste point/ Creating the point list
\def\LL{
\foreach \ii in {1,2,3,...,20}{(P-\ii) }
}
%affichage de la liste / list view
\node{\LL};

% La commande ci dessous ne fonctionne pas, que dois-je modifier?
% The command below does not work, what should I change?

%\draw plot coordinates { \LL};

%par contre, en recopiant les données affichées on peut tracer la spirale
% on the other hand, by copying the displayed data we can draw the spiral
\draw[blue] plot coordinates { (P-1) (P-2) (P-3) (P-4) (P-5) (P-6) (P-7) (P-8) (P-9) (P-10) (P-11) (P-12) (P-13)};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Remarqu:
my curve is more complex and does not depend on a single foreach but several that I want to be able to concatenate in a list then draw the corresponding curve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define your list as expanded macro, for example by using:

```
\def\LL{}
\foreach \ii in {1,2,3,...,20}{
  \xdef\LL{\LL (P-\ii)}
}
```

and then it works

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \def\RR{5}
    %calcul des coordonnées des points
    %calculation of the coordinates of the points
    \foreach \ii in {0, 1,2,3,...,20}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\aa}{360 * \ii/20}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rr}{\RR + \ii}
        \coordinate(P-\ii) at (\aa:\rr);
    }
    %dessin des points de la spirale/drawing spiral points
    \foreach \ii in {1,2,3,...,20}{
      \node[fill=black,inner sep=0,minimum size=0.2cm,circle]at (P-\ii){};
    }
    %Création de la liste point/ Creating the point list
    \def\LL{}
    \foreach \ii in {1,2,3,...,20}{
      \xdef\LL{\LL (P-\ii)}
    }
    %affichage de la liste / list view
    \node{\LL};
    % La commande ci-dessous fonctionne.
    % The command below works.
    \draw[blue] plot coordinates { \LL};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you that it answers this first problem, I will see if it works by concatenating 2 lists, I validate your answer and I will rest another if necessary

Comment: No problem to concatenate two lists : simply for the second one do not use `\def\LL{}` at the begining of the loop.

Comment: in fact I want to be able to trace a gear wheel (the one of the answerwheelhttps://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58702/creating-gears-in-tikz/58828#58828 ) in order to fill and colored the

Comment: @rpapa in this case probably you could do better than to name all coordinates. You can use `pic`, you can save the path and then reuse it, ... probably you should ask another question with what you precisely want to do.

Comment: merci, I do not know well pic, I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 11):

If I understand what is required, then (somewhat surprisingly) `\draw plot [...] (P-\x);` works, provided you set the `domain` and `samples` key correctly. Then options like `smooth` can be used.

```
\documentclass[tikz,borde=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\def\R{5}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\a=18*\i; \r=\R+\i;}] in {0, 1,...,20}
  \fill (\a:\r) coordinate (P-\i) circle [radius=0.2]
    node [anchor=\a+180, font=\tiny] {$P_{\i}$};
\draw[blue] plot [domain=0:20, samples=21,smooth] (P-\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, the coordinates can be stored in a macro (this has the advantage any coordinate format could then be used):

```
\documentclass[tikz,borde=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\def\R{5}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\a=18*\i; \r=\R+\i;}] in {0, 1,...,20}
  \fill (\a:\r) coordinate (P-\i) circle [radius=0.2]
    node [anchor=\a+180, font=\tiny] {$P_{\i}$}; 
\def\coords{}
\foreach \i in {0,...,20}{\xdef\coords{\coords(P-\i)}}
\draw[blue] plot [smooth] coordinates \coords;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both methods produce the same result:

[image]

Comment: NB [Kpym's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432013/23215) got the second bit before me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use another `\foreach` loop to draw the curve.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \def\RR{5}
    %calcul des coordonnées des points
    %calculation of the coordinates of the points
    \foreach \ii in {0, 1,2,3,...,20}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\aa}{360 * \ii/20}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rr}{\RR + \ii}
        \coordinate(P-\ii) at (\aa:\rr);
    }

    %dessin de la spirale/drawing of the spiral
    \foreach \ii in {1,2,3,...,20}{
    \node[fill=black,inner sep=0,minimum size=0.2cm,circle]at (P-\ii){};
    }

    %par contre, en recopiant les données affichées on peut tracer la spirale
    % on the other hand, by copying the displayed data we can draw the spiral
    \foreach \ii in {1,2,...,19}{
        \draw[blue] (P-\ii) -- (P-\the\numexpr\ii+1\relax);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: my curve is more complex and does not depend on a single foreach but several that I want to be able to concatenate in a list then draw the corresponding curve.

Answer (score 3):

With PSTricks, only for fun.

## Method A

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\degrees[20]
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscustom{\moveto(1,0)\multido{\i=1+1}{20}{\lineto(!\i\space dup 5 add 5 div exch PtoCrel)}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

## Method B

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\degrees[20]
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\def\pts{(1,0)}%
\multido{\i=1+1}{20}{\xdef\pts{\pts(!\i\space dup 5 add 5 div exch PtoCrel)}}
\expandafter\psline\pts
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

## Method C

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\degrees[20]
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\curvepnodes[plotpoints=21]{0}{20}{t dup 5 add 5 div exch PtoCrel}{P}
\psnline(0,\Pnodecount){P} 
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

## Method D

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\degrees[20]
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\psparametricplot[plotpoints=21]{0}{20}{t dup 5 add 5 div exch PtoCrel}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Unlimited tricks with PSTricks.