# Fill in Metapost Figure constructed in FOR loop

Tags: pdftex, metapost

I'm trying to create a wheel cog in Metapost that I would like fill in with a color. I came up with this code:

```
vardef sin(expr xx) = sind(xx) enddef;
vardef cos(expr xx) = cosd(xx) enddef;
beginfig(1)
  inc := 15;
  inner_radius := 1.0cm;
  outer_radius := 1.3cm;

  for ang = 0 step 2 * inc until 360:
    draw
      (inner_radius * sin(ang), inner_radius * cos(ang))..
      (inner_radius * sin(ang + inc), inner_radius * cos(ang +  inc))--
      (outer_radius * sin(ang + inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + inc))--
      (outer_radius * sin(ang + 2 * inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + 2 * inc))--
      (inner_radius * sin(ang + 2 * inc), inner_radius * cos(ang +  2 * inc));
  endfor;
endfig;
```

[image]

Which produces the figure I like but is there an easy way to adapt the code to fill in with a color?

Comment: Not by the computer, so just a comment:, Construct a path first with the for loop, do not forget to add `--cycle` at the end (if not you cannot fill it). Then you can draw and fill that path.

Comment: We have [done this before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58735/15036) by the way. I do not think any of the answers there was in MP -- but they could be adapted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fill` statement needs a cyclic path argument; use the `cycle` keyword to close a path. You can construct the path, store it in a variable then fill it:

```
path p;
p := for ang = 0 step 2*inc until 360 - epsilon:
    (inner_radius * sin(ang), inner_radius * cos(ang)) --
    (inner_radius * sin(ang + inc), inner_radius * cos(ang +  inc)) --
    (outer_radius * sin(ang + inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + inc)) --
    (outer_radius * sin(ang + 2 * inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + 2 * inc)) --
    (inner_radius * sin(ang + 2 * inc), inner_radius * cos(ang +  2 * inc)) --
  endfor
  cycle;
fill p withcolor 0.7white;
```

Another option is to define the path to be filled “inline“, i.e. to put the `for` loop directly after the `fill` keyword:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}

\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef sin(expr xx) = sind(xx) enddef;
vardef cos(expr xx) = cosd(xx) enddef;

beginfig(1);
  inc := 15;
  inner_radius := 1.0cm;
  outer_radius := 1.3cm;

  fill
    for ang = 0 step 2*inc until 360 - epsilon:
      (inner_radius * sin(ang), inner_radius * cos(ang)) --
      (inner_radius * sin(ang + inc), inner_radius * cos(ang +  inc)) --
      (outer_radius * sin(ang + inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + inc)) --
      (outer_radius * sin(ang + 2 * inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + 2 * inc)) --
      (inner_radius * sin(ang + 2 * inc), inner_radius * cos(ang +  2 * inc)) --
    endfor
    cycle withcolor 0.7white;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Note: although this doesn't change anything for filling, I substracted `epsilon` from 360 because it is cleaner this way (the reason is well explained in [Thruston's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651946/73317), +1). `epsilon` is 1/65536, i.e. the smallest positive number MetaPost can handle.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's take this in stages.

To make something you can fill, you need a single closed path.  Your approach of drawing a series of independent line segments needs to be adapted. So lets change your code to make a single `path`, built up one "tooth" at a time:

```
  path cog; 
  for ang = 0 step 2 * inc until 360:
      cog := if known cog: cog -- fi
      (inner_radius * sin(ang), inner_radius * cos(ang))..
      (inner_radius * sin(ang + inc), inner_radius * cos(ang + inc))--
      (outer_radius * sin(ang + inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + inc))--
      (outer_radius * sin(ang + 2 * inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + 2 * inc))--
      (inner_radius * sin(ang + 2 * inc), inner_radius * cos(ang +  2 * inc));
  endfor
  draw cog;
```

This produces the same figure -- the clever bit is in the first line of the loop.  Note that you use `:=` to update a variable.  In MP `a=b` means `a` is equal to `b`; but `a := b` means assign the value of `b` to `a`.  So here you are updating the path variable `cog` each time through the loop.  Effectively you are extending the path by doing `cog := cog -- tooth` each time.  Except that this will not work the first time, so you need to protect the very first assignment with the `if known` trick.  The first time round the loop `cog` has no value so it is not `known` so the first assignment will be `cog := tooth` as required.  Notice that the `if .. fi` is expanded in line.

So now you have a single path `cog`.  But in order to `fill` it, you need to close it, so you need one more step after the loop:  `cog := cog .. cycle;`
Like this

```
  path cog; 
  for ang = 0 step 2 * inc until 360:
      cog := if known cog: cog -- fi
      (inner_radius * sin(ang), inner_radius * cos(ang))..
      (inner_radius * sin(ang + inc), inner_radius * cos(ang + inc))--
      (outer_radius * sin(ang + inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + inc))--
      (outer_radius * sin(ang + 2 * inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + 2 * inc))--
      (inner_radius * sin(ang + 2 * inc), inner_radius * cos(ang +  2 * inc));
  endfor
  cog := cog .. cycle;
  fill cog withcolor 3/4[blue, white];
  draw cog;
```

which produces this

[image]

Ooops! There is one step too many in the loop, because you have gone from 0 to 360, so there is an extra tooth and the `& cycle` has looped back. Note that this makes no difference to the `fill`, but looks bad for the `draw`.  It is easy to fix.  Just subtract a small amount `eps` from 360 so we stop earlier:

```
  path cog; 
  for ang = 0 step 2 * inc until 360 - eps:
      cog := if known cog: cog -- fi
      (inner_radius * sin(ang), inner_radius * cos(ang))..
      (inner_radius * sin(ang + inc), inner_radius * cos(ang + inc))--
      (outer_radius * sin(ang + inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + inc))--
      (outer_radius * sin(ang + 2 * inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + 2 * inc))--
      (inner_radius * sin(ang + 2 * inc), inner_radius * cos(ang +  2 * inc));
  endfor
  cog := cog .. cycle;
  fill cog withcolor 3/4[blue, white];
  draw cog;
```

[image]

Job done?  Well not quite, because the `cog := cog ..` syntax is a bit clunky, especially as it needs the `if known` trick. And there is an Easier Way.  You can put the loop *inside* the definition of the path:

```
  path cog; cog = 
  for ang = 0 step 2 inc until 360 - eps:
      (inner_radius * sin(ang), inner_radius * cos(ang)) --
      (inner_radius * sin(ang + inc), inner_radius * cos(ang + inc)) --
      (outer_radius * sin(ang + inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + inc)) --
      (outer_radius * sin(ang + 2 inc), outer_radius * cos(ang + 2 inc)) --
      (inner_radius * sin(ang + 2 inc), inner_radius * cos(ang +  2 inc)) &
  endfor cycle;
  fill cog withcolor 3/4[blue, white];
  draw cog;
```

which is rather neater.

And having said all that, one of the nice things about MP is that you *never* have to muck about with `sind` and `cosd`.  For example, here is a different approach.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1)
  path greatc, smallc;
  greatc = fullcircle scaled 2.6 cm;
  smallc = fullcircle scaled 2.0 cm;

  numeric teeth; teeth = 12;
  path cog; cog = 
  for t = 1 upto teeth:
      subpath (8/teeth)*(t-1, t-1/2) of greatc --
      subpath (8/teeth)*(t-1/2, t)   of smallc --
  endfor cycle;

  fill cog withcolor 3/4[blue, white];
  draw cog;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to get:

[image]

with curved edges...

Finally, I am no engineer but what we have drawn looks a bit more like a [coronavirus](https://www.theparisreview.org/blog/2020/05/18/how-to-draw-the-coronavirus/) than a cog, so you might need to chamfer each tooth a bit.  Perhaps like this?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1)
  path greatc, smallc;
  greatc = fullcircle scaled 2.6 cm;
  smallc = fullcircle scaled 2.0 cm;

  numeric teeth; teeth = 12;
  numeric r; r = 1/24;
  path cog; cog = 
  for t = 1 upto teeth:
      subpath (8/teeth)*(t-1+r, t-1/2-r) of greatc --
      subpath (8/teeth)*(t-1/2+r, t-r)   of smallc --
  endfor cycle;

  fill cog withcolor 3/4[blue, white];
  draw cog;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile with `lualatex` to get this:

[image]